# Find If There Are Such Linear Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

> 1. $\def\im{\mathop{\mathrm{Im}}}$$T:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$ s.t $\ker(T)=\im(T)$
> 2. $T:\mathbb{R}^4\to \mathbb{R}^4$ s.t $\ker(T)=\im(T)$
> 3. $T:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$ s.t $T\neq 0$ and $T^3=-T$
> 4. $T:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$ s.t $T\neq 0$ and $T\neq I$ s.t for all $v\in V$ $T(v)=v$ or $T(v)=0$

1. $\dim(v)=\dim(\ker(T))+\dim(\im(T))$ so we have $3=2x\iff x=\frac{2}{3}$ so $\dim(\ker(T))=\dim(\im(T))=\frac{2}{3}$ which can not be and so there is no such linear transformation
2. by $\dim(v)=\dim(\ker(T))+\dim(\im(T))$ we get $\dim(\ker(T))=\dim(\im(T))=2$
   but if $\ker(T))=\dim(\im(T)$ then $T^2(v)=0$ and the only matrices that I know that do that are nilpotent matrices which do not work
3. $T^3=-T\iff T^3+T=0\iff T(T^2+I)=0$ So or $T=0$ which can not be or $T^2=-I$ but any number in $\mathbb{R}$ in the power of $2$ is positive so that is not such linear transformation
4. By the definition of linear transformation on basis, there is just one linear transformation that can be set on the basis vectors, so there no two matrices such that $T\neq S=0$ or $T\neq S=I$ or $\mathrm{Hom}(V\to V)$ is a linear space so there is just one identity element for addition and just one identity element for multiplication namely $I$ and $0$

Are the answers valid?

Comment: For 1.-  I would have reasoned the same. For 3.- you are right, but your reasoning is not good in my opinion. If you were in $\mathbb R^4$ you would get the same equation $T^2=-I$. But here there are matrices which sitisfy this identity. They are called complex linear structures. See for example [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_complex_structure). For 4.-, it seems to me easer consider vectors $v$ such that $T(v)=v$ and $w$ such that $T(w)=0$. Then $T(v+w)= v$, which is not $0$ neither the input. And I can't understand 2.- I think there is some  errata.

Answer (score 2):

1. What you did is correct.
2. Just take $T(a,b,c,d)=(b,0,d,0)$.
3. Just take $T(x,y,z)=(-y,x,0)$.
4. There is no such $T$, because if $v,w\in\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$ are such that $T(v)=v$ and $T(w)=0$, then $T(v+w)=v$, which is neither $v+w$ nor $0$. (I don't understand your answer here.)

Comment: 3 doesn't work..

Comment: @See-WooLee I've edited my answer. Thank you.